# Как написать ассемблер?

Tags: ассемблер

Т.е. транслятор который переводит программу с языка ассемблера в машинные команды.
Может книге какие есть?

Comment: А зачем Вам это? У Вас какой-то необычный ассемблер или как хобби, для тренировки?

Comment: как хобби, для тренировки)

Answer (score 6):

Если Вы хотите построить для тренировки всю цепочку разбора/трансляции языка в коды,
т.е. если вы хотите иметь:

- лексер
- парсер
- транслятор

то по видимому предложенный в одном из комментариев вариант с яко-бизонами будет лучшим, плюс сверху транслятор построите сами. Но это скорее промышленный подход. Я думаю для обучения будет крутовато. Есть другие варианты:

- написать всю цепочку самому руками, но выбрать более простой язык;
- взять генератор грамматик, типа бустовского [spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html), тогда не нужна будет фаза лексического анализа(но тут минус по сравнению с яко-бизонами: разбор с возвратами - очень большие файлы(типа более 10Мб будет не оч быстро парсить));
- одни мои знакомые использовали [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) были довольны;
- поискать други компромисы;
- есть [подборочка бесплатных тулзин](http://www.thefreecountry.com/programming/compilerconstruction.shtml);

А по поводу книжек: лучше всеми любимого [двухтомника от Ахо и товарищей](http://www.znaika.org/?q=teorija-sintaksicheskogo-analiza-perevoda-i-kompiljacii-tom-2) ничего не видел. Говорят его переиздали в одном томе, но это не книжка с драконом.

Answer (score 2):

Если для тренировки, то вот и книга - [Формальные языки, грамматики и основы построения трансляторов](http://window.edu.ru/window_catalog/files/r37033/stup259.pdf). :)

Ну, и возможно, еще и [Yacc & Bison](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/) пригодятся.

Comment: Сложно, но будем разбираться.

Answer (score 1):

Взять код [ассемблера](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Assembler) GNU из пакета [утилит](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Binutils) GNU и заточить под свои нужды.

Comment: Хочется как-то своими ручками обойтись.